# Latex adds a "In:" in the references of my bibliography

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography, biblatex

I had some difficulties making my references look the way I wanted in my document.

Currently, I am using these parameters for `biblatex`:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, url=false, style=authoryear, syle=verbose-ibid, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
```

I then just do a `\printbibliography` at the end of my document to display all my references.

I had struggles showing all the authors name instead of *et al.*, I also add struggles with automatic *ibid* showing but I managed to repair all that with the different parameters I added in the `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}`

Now the only thing I want to change is this annoying "In:." as shown here:
[the 'In:' problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDIXa.png)

As you can see, the In: shows the journal of the article. I want the journal to be shown, but simply not the "In:". It also makes no sense as when there is no journal specified it just shows a weird "In:." as we can see on the second reference

Here is the example of the bib where there is just this "In:." :

```
@article{burke2008coastal,
  title={Coastal capital: economic valuation of coral reefs in Tobago and St. Lucia.},
  author={Burke, Lauretta and Greenhalgh, Suzie and Prager, Daniel and Cooper, Emily and others},
  year={2008},
  publisher={World Resources Institute}
}
```

If you have any idea, it would help me a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use `\renewbibmacro{in:}{}` to completely remove the `In:`
- But maybe check if `article` is really a suitable entry type if there is no journal. The one you show in your question looks more like a report than an article ...
- There is also a typo, it should be `style` and not `syle` (although it makes not much sense to load two styles...)

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, url=false, style=authoryear, style=verbose-ibid, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{burke2008coastal,
  title={Coastal capital: economic valuation of coral reefs in Tobago and St. Lucia.},
  author={Burke, Lauretta and Greenhalgh, Suzie and Prager, Daniel and Cooper, Emily and others},
  year={2008},
  publisher={World Resources Institute}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\begin{document}

\cite{burke2008coastal}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, that works perfectly thanks! I did make a typing mistake my bad. I actually need two styles as it was the only way it would make it look the way I wanted. the `author year` in order to have the references in alphabetic order and the `verbose-ibid` so when I have two same `\cite` it doesn't display a _ibid_ but the full ref :). There must be a better way to do it of course...